# PHP Aliasing/Importing: Global Access or Alias?

Tags: php, namespaces

In PHP, there seem to be the following ways of aliasing/using a class, in this example a class residing at `\Foo\Bar`.

```
// access via global namespace
$bar = new \Foo\Bar;

// switch into namespace (probably worst option)
namespace Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

// alias namespace
use Foo;
$bar = new Foo\Bar;

// alias specific class
use Foo\Bar;
$bar = new Bar;
```

The two most common options seem to be the access via the global namespace (first option) or aliasing a specific class (last option). When should I use one over another?

Are there any established best practices in the industry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have not seen any clear recommendations in [PSR standards](http://www.php-fig.org/). Please correct me if I have missed anything here. This is why everything I write below is my personal opinion but non an established standard.

Second, I think it depends. Let me comment on every case.

```
// switch into namespace (probably worst option)
namespace Foo;
$bar = new Bar;
```

I do NOT see any reason for trying to do this and most likely this will not work. At lease you can not switch namespace many times in the same file. Check the [Defining namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php) section in PHP documentation.

> A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of
>   the file before any other code - with one exception: the declare
>   keyword.

```
// access via global namespace
$bar = new \Foo\Bar;
```

Why not? For example you might write `\PDOException` or `\stdClass` and don't import it. I personally always import classes from global namespace but this just my hobby. I do *not* see any reason for other people to do the same and I've seen a lot of examples when classes from global namespace are not imported.

```
// alias namespace
use Foo;
$bar = new Foo\Bar;
```

Not a bad idea when you need many classes from some other namespace. Common example when you import `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` for annotations. Check an example in the [Symfony Doctrine tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

This clearly shows that `Column` class belongs to `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` namespace. You do not need to import all the classes and I think it even looks better rather then when you write

```
/**
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

cause it allows to group annotations and shows that these annotations are for ORM cause you might have other annotations if you will.

```
// alias specific class
use Foo\Bar;
$bar = new Bar;
```

I think this is the most common case when you need couple classes from the namespace and use them several times. So it might improve readability if you put short names instead of name with namespace. You might [set alias](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for imported class to improve readability and to avoid conflicts.